# laravel helper not working in controller

Tags: php, laravel, php-5.6

I am trying to Create helpers in laravel. when I try to open in route it works fine but when I call in the controller function it through an error

Helper.php

```
namespace App\Helpers;


class Helper
{
public static function homePageURL()
{
    return url('/');
}
}
```

app

```
'Helper' => App\Helpers\Helper::class,
```

controller

```
  public function index()
{

        return Helper::homePageURL();


}
```

it working fine when I use this

```
Route::get('/envato-user-helper-demo', function () {
return Helper::homePageURL();
});
```

but in the controller, it shows me  This error 
`((1/1) FatalThrowableError Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Helper' not found`)

[image]

Comment: What happens if you try `\Helper::homePageURL();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, add this line at top-

```
use Helper;
```

Or you can do as **@Eleazar Resendez** says-

```
return \Helper::homePageURL();
```

Comment: its working fine when i use in route but not working in controller

Comment: @SherazKhan please see my updated answer and make a quick try